# What is the correct way to use Spring Boot ConversionService in order to convert a retrieved list of entity objects into a list of DTOs objects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

I am working on a Spring Boot application and I have the following doubt.

I have this service method (that works fine) that insert an object into the DB calling the repository:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public CoinDTO createCoin(CoinDTO coin) throws DuplicateException {
    Coin checkCoinExists = coinRepository.findByCode(coin.getCode());

    if (checkCoinExists != null) {
        String MsgErr = String.format("Coin %s already registered in the system !!! "
                + "Impossible to use POST", coin.getCode());

        log.warning(MsgErr);

        throw new DuplicateException(MsgErr);
    }

    Coin result = coinRepository.save(conversionService.convert(coin,Coin.class));
    return conversionService.convert(result,CoinDTO.class);
}
```

As you can see the **save()** methjod return the inserted **Coin** object (that is an Hibernate entity class mapping my table). The service method than convert this **Coin** object into the **CoinDTO** object in order to return the DTO object instead the entity instance. It works fine and it is the expected behavior.

Now I created this second service method that simply retrieve the list of all the **Coin** objects and must return the list of the related **CoinDTO** objects:

```
@Override
public List<CoinDTO> getCoinList() {
    
    List<Coin> coinsList = this.coinRepository.findAll();
    
    return null;
}
```

and here I have the following doubt: I think that I can implement thid **ENTITY to DTO** conversion behavior iterating on the **coinsList** element, converting each element of the list one by one and then adding it to a new **List** list. It should work

Exist some more modern and smarter way to do it? Maybe using lambda function? Can you help me to implement this behavior in a modern and a smart way?

Answer (score 2):

You may create an generic abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractConverter<T, DTO> {
    public abstract T fromDto(DTO dto);

    public abstract DTO toDTO(T t);

    public List<T> fromDTOs(List<DTO> dtos) {
        if (dtos == null || dtos.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return dtos.stream().map(this::fromDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    public List<DTO> toDTOs(List<T> ts) {
        if (ts == null || ts.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return ts.stream().map(this::toDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

}
```

Then create another class that implements the aforecreated abstract class by assigning your desired values like this:

```
@Component(value = "coinConverter")
public class CoinConverter extends AbstractConverter<Coin, CoinDTO> {

    @Override
    public Coin fromDTO(CoinDTO dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Coin coin = new Coin();
            // Assign all values you wanted to consume
            // of the following form
            // coin.setYourAttribite(dto.getYourAttribute())
            return coin;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CoinDTO toDTO(Coin coin) {
        if (t == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            CoinDTO coinDTO = new CoinDTO();
            // Assign all values you wanted to expose
            // of the following form
            // coinDTO.setYourAttribite(coin.getYourAttribute())
            return coinDTO;
        }
    }
}
```

In controller layer you may change your existing code by this one:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("coinConverter")
AbstractConverter<Coin, CoinDTO> abstractConverter;

@Override
public List<CoinDTO> getCoinList() {

    List<Coin> coinsList = this.coinRepository.findAll();
    return abstractConverter.toDTOs(cointList);
}
```

This way your code is flexible to add more converters without changing the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are looking for a way that makes the conversion process shorter and more convenient. if so use ModelMapper class in this case, read this http://modelmapper.org/ documentation, ModelMapper uses TypeTokens to allow mapping of generic parameterized types.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but is the following what you are looking for:

```java
@Override
public List<CoinDTO> getCoinList() {
    return this.coinRepository.findAll().stream()
        .map(coin -> conversionService.convert(coin, CoinDTO.class))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```